# С# Обернуть вызовы различных методов класса в единый try-catch

Tags: c#, try-catch

Абстрактный пример. Есть клиент со следующим интерфейсом:

```
public interface IUserClient
{
    Task<IUser> GetUserByIdAsync(int id);
    Task<IUser> FindUserByFirstNameAndLastNameAsync(string firstName, string lastName);
    Task<IUser> CreateUserAsync(string firstName, string lastName, string phone);
}

public interface IUser
{
    int Id { get; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Мне нужно написать обертку над этим клиентом, который будет пытаться перелогиниться, если метод клиента выбросит определенный `Exception`. Пока я реализовал это примерно так:

```
public class UserClientWrapper : IUserClient
{
    private readonly IUserClient _userClient;

    public UserClientWrapper(IUserClient userClient)
    {
        _userClient = userClient;
    }

    public async Task<IUser> GetUserByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _userClient.GetUserByIdAsync(id);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // Пытаемся перелогиниться

            try
            {
                return await _userClient.GetUserByIdAsync(id);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                // Пишем в лог, что что-то не так, и пробрасываем выше этот exception
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<IUser> FindUserByFirstNameAndLastNameAsync(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _userClient.FindUserByFirstNameAndLastNameAsync(firstName, lastName);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // Пытаемся перелогиниться

            try
            {
                return await _userClient.FindUserByFirstNameAndLastNameAsync(firstName, lastName);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                // Пишем в лог, что что-то не так, и пробрасываем выше этот exception
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<IUser> CreateUserAsync(string firstName, string lastName, string phone)
    {
        // и тут тоже самое
    }
}
```

Но вот смущает то, что я в каждом методе обязан дублировать код `try-catch`. Хотелось бы эту логику поместить в отдельный метод, но я не знаю, возможно ли это вообще. Поэтому возникает вопрос: как избежать дублирования кода в данном случае?

**P.S.** Важно! Методы клиента разные, с разными сигнатурами и возвращаемыми типами, но все они асинхронные.

Comment: Кажется, я нашел ответ тут, но пока не проверял его на своем коде: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684816/6468198

Comment: Посмотрите ответ который Grundy [писал](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52880911#52880911) в чате в ответ на [описание схожей проблемы](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52877826#52877826). PS А, кажется понял проблематику: запросы слишком разнородные, не свести к одному generic'у TRequest, TResponce

Comment: Как насчёт вынести обработку исключения в один базовый метод, передавая в качестве параметра делегат. Не сказать, чтобы я прям считал это красивым, но должно сработать

Comment: @AK да, именно это я и хотел сделать - передать делегат. Но я не мог понять, какой именно делегат требуется. Я думал, что Func<T> здесь не подойдет, поскольку у него нет входящих параметров, но потом я понял, что все же он мне подходит. В общем, вопрос отпал, ответ оформлю позже. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: [Retry pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/retry)

Comment: просто в C# нет какого-нибудь `Option<T>`/`Result<T, TError>`. Хотя, в вашем случае, можно обычный nullable использовать (`IUser?`). Т.е. это очередной пример использования исключений не по месту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел ответ [на англоязычном StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684816/6468198). Вынес логику обработки исключений в метод, в который передаю **делегат `Func<Task<T>>`**

```
public class UserClientWrapper : IUserClient
{
    private readonly IUserClient _userClient;

    public UserClientWrapper(IUserClient userClient)
    {
        _userClient = userClient;
    }

    public Task<IUser> GetUserByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return WrapClientCallAsync(() => _userClient.GetUserByIdAsync(id));
    }

    public Task<IUser> FindUserByFirstNameAndLastNameAsync(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        return WrapClientCallAsync(() => _userClient.FindUserByFirstNameAndLastNameAsync(firstName, lastName));
    }

    public Task<IUser> CreateUserAsync(string firstName, string lastName, string phone)
    {
        return WrapClientCallAsync(() => _userClient.CreateUserAsync(firstName, lastName, phone));
    }

    private async Task<T> WrapClientCallAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> function)
    {
        try
        {
            return await function();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // Пытаемся перелогиниться

            try
            {
                return await function();
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                // Пишем в лог, что что-то не так, и пробрасываем выше этот exception
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Пользователь [@aepot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot) в удаленном ответе предложил усовершенствовать метод `WrapClientCallAsync`, где вместо вложенных try-catch использовать циклы. Это может быть полезно, если попыток достаточно много, из-за чего большая вложенность может запутать. В моем случае - их 3. Я работаю с OAuth2 (Bearer) авторизацией, где есть access+refresh токены. Таким образом:

1. если первый вызов клиента вернул Unauthorized, то это значит, что
   access-токен истек и его нужно зарефрешить.
2. eсли при попытке рефреша токена снова вернулся Unathorized, это
   значит, что refresh-токен истек, и в таком случае, нужна повторная
   авторизация.

На основе вышеперечисленного получаем следующий код:

```
private async Task<T> WrapClientCallAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> function)
{
    const int retryCount = 3;

    UnauthorizedAccessException lastException = null;
    for (var attempt = 0; attempt < retryCount; attempt++)
    {
        try
        {
            await DoActionBeforeCallingClientAsync(attempt);
            return await function();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            lastException = ex;
        }
    }

    throw lastException;
}

private async Task DoActionBeforeCallingClientAsync(int attempt)
{
    var retryReason = (RetryReason) attempt;
    switch (retryReason)
    {
        case RetryReason.FirstAttempt: // На первую попытку никаких действий не требуется
            break;
        case RetryReason.AccessTokenExpired:
            await RefreshTokenAsync(); // Пытаемся зарефрешить access-токен
            break;
        case RetryReason.RefreshTokenExpired:
            await AuthenticateAsync(); // Заново логинимся
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private enum RetryReason
{
    FirstAttempt = 0,
    AccessTokenExpired = 1,
    RefreshTokenExpired = 2
}
```

Comment: Не забудьте отметить свой ответ как принятый через три (вроде бы) дня